# Angular canActivateChild parent component activation

Tags: angular

I may have misunderstood how `canActivateChild` works in Angular 11's routing.

With a route definition like the below one and `canActivateChild` returning `false`, `ParentComponent` isn't constructed but I'm expecting to have `ParentComponent` rendered while the child component not initialized and shown.

Route definition:

```js
{
  path: "parent",
  component: ParentComponent,
  canActivate: ["canActivate"],
  canActivateChild: ["canActivateChild"],
  children: [
    {
      path: "child",
      component: ChildComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ykjdox) to a full working example to demonstrate what I'm asking for.

Is this an expected behavior? Must I change my route definition to the following in order to have `ParentComponent` showing?

```js
{
  path: "parent",
  component: ParentComponent,
  canActivate: ["canActivate"],
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      canActivateChild: ["canActivateChild"],
      children: [
        {
          path: "child",
          component: ChildComponent
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same conundrum - need the parent component to be there, with just the child component "blocked". Did your proposed workaround work before? It's not working for me. I do have a workaround in using canMatch on the children instead of canActivateChild, with a catch-all route `{ path: '**', component: EmptyComponent }` registered as the last child to force some routing to succeed. Would love to have a more elegant solution though (and access to the ActivatedRouteSnapshot over just the Route in the activate-/match-guard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR;

The `canActivateChild` guards are run before `canActivate` guards and if at least one returns `false`, the `canActivate` ones won't be run anymore and the current navigation will be cancelled. In case they are helpful, [here's a link](https://github.com/Andrei0872/andreigatej.dev/blob/master/src/markdown-pages/blog/ng-router-indepth-overview.md#running-guards) to my notes on Angular Router, after spending some time reading its source code.

---

### A more detailed explanation

Whenever a navigation is about to take place, before it completes, it must go through some phases. These are all described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L556), in a big RxJS stream.

One phase of this entire process is the [guards checking](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L708).

The `checkGuards` function is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/check_guards.ts#L24-L43), as follows:

```js
/* ... */
return runCanDeactivateChecks(
              canDeactivateChecks, targetSnapshot!, currentSnapshot, moduleInjector)
      .pipe(
          mergeMap(canDeactivate => {
            return canDeactivate && isBoolean(canDeactivate) ?
                runCanActivateChecks(
                    targetSnapshot!, canActivateChecks, moduleInjector, forwardEvent) :
                of(canDeactivate);
          }),
          map(guardsResult => ({...t, guardsResult})));
});
/* ... */
```

So, as probably expected, it will run `canDeactivate` guards and if one of them fails, then the navigation will be cancelled. But, if everything is alright with `canDeactivate` guards, then `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` guards can be run.

If you scroll down a bit in the `check_guards.ts` file, you should find the `runCanActivateChecks` function:

```js
function runCanActivateChecks(
    futureSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot, checks: CanActivate[], moduleInjector: Injector,
    forwardEvent?: (evt: Event) => void) {
  return from(checks).pipe(
      concatMap((check: CanActivate) => {
        return from([
                 fireChildActivationStart(check.route.parent, forwardEvent),
                 fireActivationStart(check.route, forwardEvent),
                 // !
                 runCanActivateChild(futureSnapshot, check.path, moduleInjector),
                 runCanActivate(futureSnapshot, check.route, moduleInjector)
               ])
            .pipe(concatAll(), first(result => {
                    return result !== true;
                  }, true as boolean | UrlTree));
      }),
      first(result => {
        return result !== true;
      }, true as boolean | UrlTree));
}
```

A few interesting things happen here. First, `from(arrayOfObservables)` will emit a `next` notification that consits of `arrayOfObservables`. The first 2 observables of this array(`fire*`) are not very important right now and they simply return `of(true)`. Then, we have `runCanActivateChild` and, for now, it's important that its return type is an `Observable<boolean|UrlTree>`. If we look below, we have `concatAll()`, which subscribes to each observable and queues the new ones that arrive until the current inner observable completes.
Then, `first(...)` makes sure that if we encounter any value **which is not** `true`, then we should stop.

Let's take your example. If a `canActivateChild` guard returns false, then `runCanActivate` won't be run, and the `guardResult` value(2 snippets above) will be `false`. And if that happens, then the [navigation will be cancelled](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L725);

```js
 filter(t => {
  if (!t.guardsResult) {
    this.resetUrlToCurrentUrlTree();
    const navCancel =
        new NavigationCancel(t.id, this.serializeUrl(t.extractedUrl), '');
    eventsSubject.next(navCancel);
    t.resolve(false);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}),
```

So, this is why your example is not working as expected. If you'd like to read more about the inner workings of Angular Router, I'd recommend checking out these articles:

- [Angular Router: Getting to know UrlTree, ActivatedRouteSnapshot and ActivatedRoute](https://andreigatej.dev/blog/angular-router-urlree)
- [Angular Router: Revealing some interesting facts and features](https://indepth.dev/posts/1379/angular-router-revealing-some-interesting-facts-and-features)
- [Demystifying angular/router: what is RouterScroller and why is it useful ?](https://indepth.dev/posts/1366/demystifying-angular-router-what-is-routerscroller-and-why-is-it-useful-2)

Comment: With your extensive knowledge of the Angular Router, can you recommend a routes configuration that achieves what OP was looking for? That is: To have router.navigateByUrl("/parent/child") cause the parent to be loaded, but not the child, if some "guard function" fails for the child, but not the parent.